# return a Pandas Series inside of pandas_udf spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-arrow

on Apache Spark I have a pandas_udf function that should return a pd.Series How can this be archived?

I tried:

```
@pandas_udf(ArrayType(LongType()), PandasUDFType.SCALAR_ITER) # Only works with spark 3.0
def udf(iterator):
  ...
  return pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
```

this gives the exception:

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowNotImplementedError: NumPyConverter doesn't implement <list<item: int64>> conversion.
```

Comment: Can you share what you want to achieve with some example data ?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to achieve something like this:

```
+---+-----+---------------+
| id|value|     sample_col|
+---+-----+---------------+
|  1|    1|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|
|  2|    4|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|
|  3|    9|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|
|  4|   16|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|
|  5|   25|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|
+---+-----+---------------+
```

then, below should do the job.

```
@pandas_udf(T.ArrayType(T.IntegerType())) 
def _udf(iterator:pd.Series) -> pd.Series:  
    result = pd.Series([[1,2,3,4,5] for _ in range(len(iterator))])
    return result
```

```
sdf.withColumn('sample_col',_udf((F.col('value')))).show()
```

Answer (score -2):

ok this was an error on my side.    Schema type from pandas udf

Comment: what is the solution?